# How to substract the results of queries from each other?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please consider the following

```
select name
into #list_1
from table_1
-- result: a, b, c, d, e

select name
into #list_2
from table_2
-- result: b, e

select name
into #list_3
from table_3
-- result: a

select ??
-- result: 1 - 2 - 3 = c, d
```

Spread among my script, I have 3 temp tables, all holding people's names. `#list_1` contains the full list. How can I substract the values in `#list_2` and `#list_3` from `#list_1` so that I get the difference as a result?

I'm on SQL server 2008. If I'm looking at this all wrong, then please let me know. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `except` in SQL Server.  But I prefer using `not exists` because it is standard SQL:

```
select l1.name
from table_1 l1
where not exists (select 1 from table_2 l2 where l2.name = l1.name) and
      not exists (select 1 from table_3 l3 where l3.name = l1.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

something like

```
select name from Table_1
except
select name from Table_2
except
Select name From Table_3
```

no need for the temp tables to do it.